# Force reload of entity in Entity Framework after insert/add

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Project` entity, defined as:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    //...
    [Required, ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }    
}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
// insert
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] ProjectDTO projectDTO)
{
    return Save(projectDTO);
}

// update
public IHttpActionResult Post(Guid id, [FromBody] ProjectDTO projectDTO)
{
    return Save(projectDTO);
}

private IHttpActionResult Save(ProjectDTO projectDTO)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var isNew = projectDTO.ProjectId == Guid.Empty;

    Project project;
    if (isNew)
    {
        project = new Project();
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
        projectDTO.UserId = new Guid(user.UserId.ToString());

        DbContext.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        project= DbContext.Projects.Find(projectDTO.ProjectId);
        if (project == null) return NotFound();

        DbContext.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // set fields from DTO to User...

    DbContext.SaveChanges();

    // issue:

    return Ok(project);
}
```

The issue is that when a newly inserted project is returned by the controller, the virtual field `User` will be null because it hasn't been loaded/populated with the User data.

On the line `// issue:` I tried both of these lines:

```
if (isNew)
{
    // try one of these two lines:
    DbContext.Entry(project).Reload();
    project = DbContext.Projects.Find(project.ProjectId);
}
```

But both had no effect: I assume using the `Find` is not actually going back to the database because the entity already exists in the context, so it just returns that. But I would have thought the reload would have forced a full reload of the project with FK relationships, but it didn't.

I could do something like this:

```
if (isNew)
{
    project.User = DbContext.Users.Find(project.UserId);
}
```

But that doesn't look as clean as I'd like: I'd have to do it for each FK that I'm returning.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: don't understand your `Project` class, I thought `User` here is a navigation property? but you add `[ForeignKey("User")]` for `UserId`? I thought you need to apply `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` for `User` property? This is just a side-note from your problem.

Comment: Your new project has no more info attached on it after being created with `new Project()`, I thought you had to assign the `UserId` or `User` right after that? but instead you set `UserId` on `projectDTO`?

Comment: @Hopeless I set the `projectDTO.UserId` because later on I set all fields from the `projectDTO` to the `project`. Sorry, I should have made that explicit. Not sure about the ForeignKey question - works for me but I'll look that one up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detach it first, this should force the reloading upong finding:

```
DbContext.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Detached;
project = DbContext.Projects.Find(project.ProjectId);
```

If that doesn't work, you could detach it using the `ObjectContext` instead, but that will probably stop working on future versions of EF (where `DbContext` doesn't use `ObjectContext`):

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.Detach(project);
```

Comment: Surely this is what `Reload()` was added for - any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Sean I believe `Reload` uses `ObjectContext.Refresh` (with `StoreWins`) internally, which doesn't reload navigation properties aswell (although I'm not 100% sure). This has been a pain in the ass since the times of EF4. They'll get it right in EF7, I hope :-)

Comment: @Sean 2.5 years later, problem still persists.  I ended up just creating a new DbContext and using `find`